# length of a n dimensional array in python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
filepath = 'test.xlsx'
A = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
B = np.size(A)
print(B)
```

Is there any function in python similar to numel in matlab ?
I am trying to print the number of elements in an array. This excel sheet has 1x19 elements. I was expecting the output to be 19 but it is giving me output as 0.

Comment: You are looking for `A.size`, but `np.size(A)` should work. If the output is `0` that's because there are 0 elements. Something is wrong with your data or how you are trying to read it

Comment: No there are 19 elements in the sheet (1 row and 19 columns).

Comment: Well *apparently* there is not. As I stated, if you are getting `0`, it's because your data-frame has zero elements. Somewhere, your data is not correctly getting read into the dataframe. You haven't provided enough enough for us to help you figure out what is going on, you'd have to provide a [mcve]

Comment: No,there are 19 elements in that excel sheet. Even in my variable explorer, it is showing A is a dataframe with size (0,19) and the values of the elements. But the size it is showing is wrong

Comment: A dataframe of size `(0,19)` **doesn't haven any elements in it**. 0*19 == 0. Likely, you are reading a single row as a header, and then it isn't finding any data. Just do some basic debugging. And almost always, when you think `numpy` or some often used library is "wrong" it is *you* not the library. Anyay, try passing `header=None` to `pd.read_csv`

Comment: provide the head of "A"

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Sheet1` (capital "S") as the specified sheet name, as that might be the real name.  That's how Excel names sheets by default.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> filepath = r'C:\tmp\test.xlsx'
>>> A = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name='Sheet1')
>>> print(np.size(A))
9
```

Otherwise, the function should work.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)])
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> print(A.size)
9
>>> print(np.size(A))
9
>>> print(len(A))
3
```